# SQL for searching username efficiently

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with userID, userFirstName, userLastName as fields and lots of records in it. I have to list all users similar to the key value received from user. I have it as $searchKey in my program. 
If the user searches with a string namely "Robert" ,
the result should give related values to Robert first,
 then to Rober ,
 then to Robe ,
 then Rob,
 then Ro ,
 and finally R.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You might want to consider using a 3rd party search tool, instead of the built in features of the database. They are rather limited. Things like Elasticsearch are far more powerful when it comes to complex search requirements.

Comment: I use mysql @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is with a `case` statement in the `order by`:

```
order by (case where col like '%Robert%' then 1
               where col like '%Rober%' then 2
               where col like '%Robe%' then 3
               where col like '%Rob%' then 4
               where col like '%Ro%' then 5
               where col like '%R%' then 6
          end)
```

Comment: You should really try to get rid of the leading `%` in the value. Having it there is going to neutralize any index on the column, which is going to murder the performance of the query.

Comment: Or just use a FULLTEXT index.

Comment: I want the result to be unique. ie. there must be no repeated values. How would i do that? And the order by statement sorts the result. I dont want a sorted list. The most related result for the search key should be first.